# TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print('\n'*50)
from time import sleep, time
from random import *
print('hello, im your freind')
print('I\'ll help you through journey if you type h')
cont = input('CONTINUE?')
class cls():
def mage():
    w = 5
    rng = 5
    spd = 2
    c = 1
    hp = 50
    rideable = 0
    g = 10
def warrior():
    w = 10
    rng = 3
    spd = 1
    c = 2
    hp = 100
    rideable = 0

def archer():
    w = 7.5
    rng = 10
    spd = 1.5
    c = 3
    hp = 75
    rideable = 0
    print('y')
def healer():
    w = 2.5
    rng = 5
    healpow = 5
    c = 4
    hp = 50
    spd = 3
    rideable = 0
def robotic_horse():
    rideable = 1
    w = 1
    bspd = 10
    hp = 50
    c = 5
    spd = 10
class ecls():
def elf():
    ehp = 10
    eatck = 5
    espd = 5
    erng = 7
    ec = 4
    erideable = 0
def mech():
    ehp = 200
    eatck = 10
    espd = 0.5
    erng = 2
    ec = 1
    erideable = 1
    ebspd = 0.5
def goblin():
    ehp = 25
    eatck = 2.5
    espd = 5
    erng = 1
    ec = 2
    erideble = 0
def gang():
    ehp = 300
    eatck = 5
    espd = 2.5
    erng = 3
    ec = 3
    erideble = 5
if cont == 'no':
sleep(0)
else:
def fight():
    enemies = open('saveFile.txt','r').readlines(1)
    print('\n'*50)
    xp = 0
    heals = 10
    #choose class
    print('Choose your Class:')
    print('mage(1)')
    print('warrior(2)')
    print('archer(3)')
    print('healer(4)')
    chc = input('')
    if chc == '1':
        w = 5
        rng = 5
        spd = 2
        c = 1
        hp = 50
        rideable = 5
        g = 10
    if chc == '2':
        w = 10
        rng = 3
        spd = 1
        c = 2
        hp = 100
        rideable = 5
    if chc == '3':
        w = 7.5
        rng = 10
        spd = 1.5
        c = 3
        hp = 75
        rideable = 5
    if chc == '4':
        w = 2.5
        rng = 5
        healpow = 5
        c = 4
        hp = 50
        spd = 3
        rideable = 5
    if chc == '5':
        rideable = 5
        w = 3
        bspd = 10
        hp = 50
        c = 5
        spd = 10
        bw = 5
    else:
        w = 7.5
        rng = 10
        spd = 1.5
        c = 3
        hp = 75
        rideable = 0
    ehp = 10
    ew = 5
    espd = 5
    erng = 7
    ec = 4
    erideable = 0
    print('\n'*50)
    ups = 10
    eheals = 0
    while enemies > 0 and hp > 0:
        #Head Down Display or for short HDD
        print('THIS IS THE HDD:')
        print('health', hp)
        print('enemy health', ehp)
        print('upgrades', ups)
        print('heals', heals)
        print('enemies', enemies)
        attack = input('attack(1) defend(2) heal(3) upgrade(4)')
        if attack == '1':
            ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
        if attack == '2':
            ew = ew - .05
        if attack == '3':
            if heals == 0:
                print('all out!')
            else:
                heals = heals - 1
                hp = hp + 35
        if attack == 'h':
            print('attack attack\'s, defend defend\'s, heal heal\'s, upgrade upgrade\'s')
        if attack == '4':
            if ups < 1:
                print('all out')
            else:
                ups = ups - 1
                w = w + 1
        if attack == 'save':
                saveFile = open('saveFile.txt','w')
                saveFile.write(enemies)
        else:
            ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
        if rideable < 5:
            print('THIS IS THE HDD:')
            print('health', hp)
            print('enemy health', ehp)
            print('upgrades', ups)
            print('heals', heals)
            print('enemies', enemies)
            attack = input('attack(1) defend(2) heal(3) upgrade(4)')
            if attack == '1':
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
            if attack == '2':
                ew = ew - .05
            if attack == '3':
                if heals == 0:
                    print('all out!')
                else:
                    heals = heals - 1
                    hp = hp + 35
            if attack == 'h':
                print('attack attack\'s, defend defend\'s, heal heal\'s, upgrade upgrade\'s')
            if attack == '4':
                if ups < 1:
                    print('all out')
                else:
                    ups = ups - 1
                    w = w + 1
            if attack == 'save':
                saveFile = open('saveFile.txt','w')
                saveFile.write(enemies)
            else:
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
        if rideable < 4:
            print('THIS IS THE HDD:')
            print('health', hp)
            print('enemy health', ehp)
            print('upgrades', ups)
            print('heals', heals)
            print('enemies', enemies)
            attack = input('attack(1) defend(2) heal(3) upgrade(4)')
            if attack == '1':
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
            if attack == '2':
                ew = ew - .05
            if attack == '3':
                if heals == 0:
                    print('all out!')
                else:
                    heals = heals - 1
                    hp = hp + 35
            if attack == 'h':
                print('attack attack\'s, defend defend\'s, heal heal\'s, upgrade upgrade\'s')
            if attack == '4':
                if ups < 1:
                    print('all out')
                else:
                    ups = ups - 1
                    w = w + 1
            if attack == 'save':
                saveFile = open('saveFile.txt','w')
                saveFile.write(enemies)
            else:
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
        if rideable < 3:
            print('THIS IS THE HDD:')
            print('health', hp)
            print('enemy health', ehp)
            print('upgrades', ups)
            print('heals', heals)
            print('enemies', enemies)
            attack = input('attack(1) defend(2) heal(3) upgrade(4)')
            if attack == '1':
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
            if attack == '2':
                ew = ew - .05
            if attack == '3':
                if heals == 0:
                    print('all out!')
                else:
                    heals = heals - 1
                    hp = hp + 35
            if attack == 'h':
                print('attack attack\'s, defend defend\'s, heal heal\'s, upgrade upgrade\'s')
            if attack == '4':
                if ups < 1:
                    print('all out')
                else:
                    ups = ups - 1
                    w = w + 1
            if attack == 'save':
                saveFile = open('saveFile.txt','w')
                saveFile.write(enemies)
            else:
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
        if rideable < 2:
            print('THIS IS THE HDD:')
            print('health', hp)
            print('enemy health', ehp)
            print('upgrades', ups)
            print('heals', heals)
            print('enemies', enemies)
            attack = input('attack(1) defend(2) heal(3) upgrade(4)')
            if attack == '1':
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
            if attack == '2':
                ew = ew - .05
            if attack == '3':
                if heals == 0:
                    print('all out!')
                else:
                    heals = heals - 1
                    hp = hp + 35
            if attack == 'h':
                print('attack attack\'s, defend defend\'s, heal heal\'s, upgrade upgrade\'s')
            if attack == '4':
                if ups < 1:
                    print('all out')
                else:
                    ups = ups - 1
                    w = w + 1
            if attack == 'save':
                saveFile = open('saveFile.txt','w')
                saveFile.write(enemies)
            else:
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
        if rideable < 1:
            print('THIS IS THE HDD:')
            print('health', hp)
            print('enemy health', ehp)
            print('upgrades', ups)
            print('heals', heals)
            print('enemies', enemies)
            attack = input('attack(1) defend(2) heal(3) upgrade(4)')
            if attack == '1':
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
            if attack == '2':
                ew = ew - .05
            if attack == '3':
                if heals == 0:
                    print('all out!')
                else:
                    heals = heals - 1
                    hp = hp + 35
            if attack == 'h':
                print('attack attack\'s, defend defend\'s, heal heal\'s, upgrade upgrade\'s')
            if attack == '4':
                if ups < 1:
                    print('all out')
                else:
                    ups = ups - 1
                    w = w + 1
            if attack == 'save':
                saveFile = open('saveFile.txt','w')
                saveFile.write(enemies)
            else:
                ehp = ehp - (w + randint(-1, 1))
        #ENEMYS TURN
        dec = randint(1, 3)
        if ehp > 0:
            if dec == 1:
                hp = hp - ew
            if dec == 2:
                w = w - 0.25
            if dec == 3:
                if eheals < 10:
                    ehp = ehp + 1
            erand = randint(1, 250)
            if erand == 10:
                print('New Enemy Spotted')
                print('Enemy\'s Heals Restored')
                print('Enemy\'s Health Restored')
                print('He Attacks You Once')
                print('Ouch!')
                eheals = 0
                if ec == 1:
                    heals = 10
                    ehp = 200
                    hp = hp - 25
                    eheals = 10
                if ec == 2:
                    ehp = 25
                    hp = hp - 25
                    eheals = 10
                if ec == 3:
                    ehp = 300
                    hp = hp - 25
                    eheals = 10
                if ec == 4:
                    ehp = 10
                    hp = hp - 25
                    eheals = 10
                print('New enemy Leaves')
            rand = randint(1, 250)
            if rand == 10:
                print('New Freind Spotted')
                print('Your\'s Upgrades Restored')
                print('Your\'s Health Restored')
                print('He Attacks The Enemy Once')
                print('Yes!')
                eheals = 0
                if c == 1:
                    hp = 50
                    ups = 25
                    ehp = ehp - 25
                if c == 2:
                    hp = 100
                    ups = 25
                    ehp = ehp - 25
                if c == 3:
                    hp = 75
                    ups = 25
                    ehp = ehp - 25
                if c == 4:
                    hp = 50
                    ups = 25
                    ehp = ehp - 25
                if c == 5:
                    hp = 99999999
                    ups = 25
                    ehp = ehp - 25
                print('New Freind Leaves')
            rand = randint(1, 250)
            if rand == 10:
                print('New Freind Spotted')
                if rideable > 0:
                    print('He Joins Your Team!')
                    rideable = rideable - 1
                    if c == 1:
                        hp = 50
                        ups = 25
                        ehp = ehp - 25
                    if c == 2:
                        hp = 100
                        ups = 25
                        ehp = ehp - 25
                    if c == 3:
                        hp = 75
                        ups = 25
                        ehp = ehp - 25
                    if c == 4:
                        hp = 50
                        ups = 25
                        ehp = ehp - 25
                    if c == 5:
                        hp = 99999999
                        ups = 25
                        ehp = ehp - 25
        else:
            heals = 10
            eheals = 0
            enemies = enemies - 1
            print('you\'ve defeated him!')
            print(enemies, ' left to go!')
            print('looking for opponent')
            sleep(randint(1, 10))
            enemy = randint(1, 4)
            if enemy == 1:
                ehp = 10
                ew = 5
                espd = 5
                erng = 7
                ec = 4
                erideable = 0
            if enemy == 2:
                ehp = 200
                ew = 10
                espd = 0.5
                erng = 2
                ec = 1
                erideable = 1
                ebspd = 0.5
            if enemy == 3:
                ehp = 25
                ew = 2.5
                espd = 5
                erng = 1
                ec = 2
                erideble = 0
            if enemy == 4:
                ehp = 300
                ew = 5
                espd = 2.5
                erng = 3
                ec = 3
                erideble = 5
        print('\n'*50)
#MAIN GAME LOOP
fight()
print('\n'*50)
print('score', hp)
```

the code comes up with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python34\war.py", line 464, in <module> 
fight()
File "C:\Python34\war.py", line 146, in fight
while enemies > 0 and hp > 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

Comment: `file.readlines` returns a list, so `enemies` is a list and `enemies > 0` will raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: `enemies` is a list. What do you expect to get from comparing a list to an integer? Did you mean `while len(enemies)>0`?

Comment: All those `def`s inside the `class`es make no sense at all. You really should read up on classes in python.

Comment: All those functions... all those if statements... none of this makes any sense. It's like reading a story with no punctuation or capital letters, no chapters, no quotes around the dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to think that `enemies` is an integer (since you subtract one from it at one point and compare it to zero in another), but it's a list of strings.  I think you may want to make it an `int`, as follows:

when saving, instead of:

```
saveFile.write(enemies)
```

use:

```
saveFile.write(str(enemies) + '\n')
```

when reloading, instead of:

```
enemies = open('saveFile.txt','r').readlines(1)
```

use:

```
enemies = int(open('saveFile.txt','r').readline().strip())
```